# Chrome Extension: invoking background when URL update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an auto login extension for certain websites.

The goal is to create a background script that receive an update every time that the active tab URL's change.

After many tries I'm still not succeeding to catch that event so ill be able to invoke my code.

my **manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "OpenU AutoLogin",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
},
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "OUAL48.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js":["OUAL.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_url>", "background"
  ]
}
```

my **background.js:** (the SendScriptIntoActiveTab function works just fine)

```
    chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    SendScriptIntoActiveTab({code:"console.log(changeInfo);"});
 });

 function SendScriptIntoActiveTab(code){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,code, function(response) {
         });
       });
  }
```

but sadly nothing is happening when I'm running from the background.
any one have any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.onActivated` signature is wrong. Also, you need to use `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` to listen to tab URL changes.

From the docs:

> onActivated
>
> Fires when the active tab in a window changes. Note that the tab's URL
>   may not be set at the time this event fired, but you can listen to 
>   onUpdated events so as to be notified when a URL is set.

To check if the active tab URL has changed:

```js
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (activeInfo.tabId === tabId && changeInfo.url) {
       console.log(`URL has changed to ${changeInfo.url}`)
    }
  })
})
```